# WSO2 ESB DSS Integration, sending multiple records to DSS

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

i have requirement where in i have to insert multiple values from `ESB 4.8.1` into `Oracle Database table` via `WSO2 DSS`.

Oracle DB table (Student) consists of below fields

```
1) Id
2) Name
3) Class
4) School Name
```

- `ESB` will receive a `SOAP` request which consists of 200 student records with above fields, here range is 200 which may vary.
- In `ESB` i will extract the 200 record values(200 student details), let say 200 insert statements.
- From ESB how i can send these 200 record values to DSS in a single SOAP request, so that DSS will take care of inserting 200 records into DB.

Can DSS receive SOAP Request which contains multiple records (200 students details) and insert into DB.?

Looking forward for the necessary help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it´s possible.
In the data service configuration just add: enableBatchRequests="true".

Take a look at https://dzone.com/articles/wso2-dss-batch-insert-sample

Answer (score 1):

The batch requests feature allows you to send multiple (IN-Only) requests to a datasource using a single operation (batch operation)in WSO2 DSS(Data Services Server). You can get a clear picture with examples in the following link.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/DSS351/Invoking+an+Operation+with+Multiple+Records

Additionally the request box feature allows you to invoke multiple operations (consecutively) to a datasource using a single operation in WSO2 DSS. See the following link.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/DSS351/Invoking+Multiple+Operations+via+Request+Box

Now you can use these features together (ESB+DSS) in the WSO2 EI (Enterprise Integrator). Check https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Data+Integration and https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Upgrading+from+WSO2+Data+Services+Server